# class decorator for methods

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have a decorator that decorates class methods that don't start with two underscores.

```py
def log_methods(date_format):
    def decorator(cls):

        for attr_name in dir(cls):
            attr = getattr(cls, attr_name)
            if callable(attr) and not attr_name.startswith('__'):
                def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                    start = datetime.now()
                    print(f'Starting {attr.__qualname__} date and time {start.strftime(date_format)}')
                    result = attr(*args, **kwargs)
                    end = datetime.now()
                    print(f'Finishing  {attr.__qualname__}, function operation time: {end.strftime(date_format)}')
                    return result

                setattr(cls, attr_name, wrapper)

        return cls

    return decorator

@log_methods("%b %d %Y - %H:%M:%S")
class A:
    new_class_attr = 2

    def test_func(self):
        print('test_func called')


a = A()
a.test_func()
```

I decided to find out what would happen if I decorated the class attribute. To do this, I removed the `callable(attr)` check from the condition. The decorator for the `new_class_attr` attribute has been added, but I don't understand why the `test_func` method is executed when calling?

```py
def log_methods(date_format):
    def decorator(cls):

        for attr_name in dir(cls):
            attr = getattr(cls, attr_name)
            if not attr_name.startswith('__'):
                def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                    start = datetime.now()
                    print(f'Starting {attr.__qualname__} date and time {start.strftime(date_format)}')
                    result = attr(*args, **kwargs)
                    end = datetime.now()
                    print(f'Finishing  {attr.__qualname__}, function operation time: {end.strftime(date_format)}')
                    return result

                setattr(cls, attr_name, wrapper)

        return cls

    return decorator


@log_methods("%b %d %Y - %H:%M:%S")
class A:
    new_class_attr = 2

    def test_func(self):
        print('test_func called')


a = A()
a.new_class_attr() # The test_func method is called
```

Comment: your decorators will never work properly they are subjects of a loop-side effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment your decorator (the 1st) will never work properly.
Let test it with a modified class:

```
from datetime import datetime

# ... 

@log_methods("%b %d %Y - %H:%M:%S") # OP 1st decorator
class A:

    def test_func(self):
        return('test_func called')

    def test_func_X(self):
        return('test_funcX called')


a = A()
print(a.test_func())
#test_funcX called
print(a.test_func_X())
#test_funcX called
```

All callable functions will point to the last (in alphabetical order) function edited. You can check it with `inspect.source` which extract the body of the function as plain text.

```
from inspect import getsource

src1 = getsource(a.test_func)
src2 = getsource(a.test_func_X)
print(src1 == src2)
# True
```

You need a further parametrization of the decorator for the methods

```
def log_methods(date_format):
    def decorator(cls):

        def __wrapper(func):
            def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                start = datetime.now()
                print(f'Starting {attr.__qualname__} date and time {start.strftime(date_format)}')
                result = func(*args, **kwargs) # <-
                end = datetime.now()
                print(f'Finishing  {attr.__qualname__}, function operation time: {end.strftime(date_format)}')
                return result
            return wrapper
        
        for attr_name in dir(cls):
            attr = getattr(cls, attr_name)
            if callable(attr) and not attr_name.startswith('__'):
                setattr(cls, attr_name, __wrapper(attr))           # <-

        return cls

    return decorator
```

---

For the 2nd decorator, you need to distinguish between callable and not... otherwise what do you expect to get with `a.new_class_attr()`? ... the same as calling an integer: `2()`!

Hint: `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`

Comment: `For the 2nd decorator, you need to distinguish between callable and not... otherwise what expected to get with a.new_class_attr()? ... the same as calling an integer: 2()!` 
Yes, having made such a call, I wanted to get an error

Thanks for the explanation and examples!